# Videogular fails to play video

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, video, videogular

I have dynamically binded the video src tag using angular.But videogular fails to append the video url.

Below is my videogular tag with angular bind expression where it binds video url dynamically.

```
<vg-media 
vg-src='[{src: "{{selectedVideo.Uris[0].AbsolutePath}}", type:   "video/mp4"}]'
vg-loop="controller.config.plugins.controls.loop"
vg-preload="controller.config.plugins.controls.preload">
</vg-media>
```

But you can see in the Image below.When page is running the video src is binded to the videogular-src tag but not to the video tag.Angular binding expression is showing.Videogular fails to play video.

[image]

How to make it play.
Need help!

Comment: Remove double quote  like this  `vg-src='[{src: {{selectedVideo.Uris[0].AbsolutePath}}, type:   "video/mp4"}]' `

Comment: Well..Worked after removing the {{}} binding expression.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video URL must be trusted by AngularJS $sce provider.

In your controller:

```
this.getVideo = function(){
    {
        src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4"),
        type: "video/mp4"
    }
};
```

In your vg-media tag:

```
<vg-media vg-src="ctrl.getVideo()">
```

Comment: You have a more complex example here: https://github.com/2fdevs/videogular/blob/master/app/scripts/controllers/main.js

Comment: Sorted the issue out.Anyways thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with videogular and Angular 12 wanted to show a video from google cloud storeage, the video player worked fine on safari but not on chrome and firefox, so long story short the problem was the video file itself, I changed the video and it worked, hope it works for you too.